# Spring Integration new file callback?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using `FileWritingMessageHandler` with a custom `FileNameGenerator` which generates new filenames in intervals (similar to rolling file appender for `log4j`).

```
@Slf4j
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RolloverFileNameGenerator extends AbstractExpressionEvaluator implements FileNameGenerator {
  private final Map<CachedFileEvaluation, String> cache;
  private final RoundedBucketIntervalCalculator intervalCalculator;
  private final Map<String, Object> commonContext;
  private final Expression nameExpression;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public RolloverFileNameGenerator(final RoundedBucketIntervalCalculator intervalCalculator,
                                   final String nameExpression, final Map<String, Object> context, final int cacheMaxSize) {
    this(new LRUMap(cacheMaxSize), intervalCalculator, context, EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression(nameExpression));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public RolloverFileNameGenerator(final RoundedBucketIntervalCalculator intervalCalculator, final String nameExpression, final Map<String, Object> context) {
    this(null, intervalCalculator, context, EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression(nameExpression));
  }

  @Override
  public String generateFileName(final Message<?> message) {
    return generateFileName(message, DateTime.now());
  }

  public String generateFileName(final Message<?> message, final DateTime dateTime) {
    final Interval interval = intervalCalculator.getInterval(dateTime);

    if (cache == null) {
      return evaluateFilenameFromMessage(message, interval);
    }

    final Optional<String> cached = cache.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().isBetweenInclusive(dateTime))
        .findFirst()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue);

    return cached.orElseGet(() -> {
      final String evaluatedValue = evaluateFilenameFromMessage(message, interval);
      cache.putIfAbsent(new CachedFileEvaluation(interval), evaluatedValue);
      return evaluatedValue;
    });
  }

  private String evaluateFilenameFromMessage(final Message<?> message, final Interval interval) {
    final Object evaluated = this.evaluateExpression(nameExpression, new RolloverEvaluationContext(commonContext, interval, message));

    if (evaluated == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Evaluated expression is valid, but it resulted with a null");
    }

    if (!(evaluated instanceof String)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Evaluated expression is valid, but it didn't result in a String. Evaluated result: (%s) %s", evaluated.getClass(), evaluated));
    }

    return (String) evaluated;
  }

  @Data
  @AllArgsConstructor
  public class CachedFileEvaluation {
    private Interval interval;

    public boolean isBetweenInclusive(final DateTime date) {
      return interval.contains(date) || interval.getEnd().isEqual(date);
    }
  }

  @Getter
  @AllArgsConstructor
  private class RolloverEvaluationContext {
    private final Map<String, Object> ctx;
    private final Interval interval;
    private final Message<?> message;
  }
}
```

From my configuration:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "com.github.alturkovic.rollover.writer", name = "initialize", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public FileWritingMessageHandler fileWritingMessageHandler(final RolloverFileNameGenerator rolloverFileNameGenerator) {
  final Writer writer = properties.getWriter();

  final FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(properties.getDirectory()));
  handler.setAppendNewLine(writer.isAppendNewLine());
  handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(writer.isAutoCreateDirectory());
  handler.setFileExistsMode(writer.getMode());
  handler.setFlushInterval(writer.getFlushInterval());
  handler.setFileNameGenerator(rolloverFileNameGenerator);
  handler.setOutputChannelName("nullChannel");
  return handler;
}
```

Each time a new file has to be created, I would like to write a CSV header to it. I have looked into `FileWritingMessageHandler` and I can't figure out how to accomplish what I am trying to.

Could someone point me in the right direction if this can be done without changing `FileWritingMessageHandler` source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep some state and simply write the header in `RolloverFileNameGenerator.generateFileName()`.

```
if (!newName.equals(lastName) {
    // write header
}
```

Comment: Sure, I might have oversimplified the purpose of the `RolloverFileNameGenerator` since it actually derives the filename according to the timestamp of the message, so the filename it generates is not "incremental" and it is possible to have the following sequence generated: `a,b,a,c`. I have thought about checking if the file exists and writing the header then, but then I would have to duplicate `FileExistsMode` logic from the `FileWritingMessageHandler`.

Comment: It's not really duplicating it; presumably you are using one of the APPEND modes; you know for sure that if the file is not there, it doesn't have a header. But, yes, it does mean another test against the file system. You could use a `Map` or similar to see if you've already evaluated to the same file name (but then you'd need some mechanism to remove stale entries).

Comment: I assume I would need additional atomicity control as well... Would a `NewFileCallback` in `FileWritingMessageHandler` be wrong by design? If not, I would gladly try to submit a PR.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable enhancement to me [Contributor Guidelines here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc).